# Как можно обойти систему проверки sql-запроса на уязвимость?

Tags: mysql, sql, безопасность, sql-injection

На сервер поступает `sql-запрос` в текстовом виде от администратора. Запрос выполняется исключительно на `SELECT`. На стороне `php` проводятся проверки на команды типа: `DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, TRUNCATE, DROP, CREATE...`. Но есть способ как-то передать эти команды, но не в стандартном виде?

Например, на `php`(и не только в нем) есть возможность с помощью `eval` передать команду в не стандартном виде и с помощью манипуляций запустить ее в нужном для интерпретаторе в виде, как зачастую с вирусами бывает. Например, слово в реверсе и т.п.

Comment: Зависит от того, как именно делается проверка на SELECT, как запрос исполняется и еще от того, что за БД используется. Если все правильно реализовано, то нельзя. Если же нет, то можно сделать запрос, который будут формально select запросом, но при этом еще будет и модифицировать данные.

Comment: на ключевые слова в регистронезависимом поиске

Comment: Исполняйте его от пользователя без прав на изменение данных.

Comment: @nazarpunk как это поможет решить вопрос? В вопросе же о том как обойти, а не, как сделать, чтоб нельзя было обойти

Comment: @RomanKonoval так вы со стороны кулхацкинга интересуетесь?

Comment: @nazarpunk не я. Это автор вопроса интересуется.